# ROS TURTLESIM using PYTHON

Tags: ros, python

In ROS TURTLESIM, While moving the turtle in circle using the linear velocity and angular velocity , how do i track the distance so as to stop the turtle moving after one revolution ??

Comment: If this worked can u provide me with the script please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a distance function with the maximum value being the circumference, use rospy's Time function to update distance and whenever the current_distance exceeds the circumference, publish a zero velocity msg to stop the turtle.

Comment: How do i use rospy's time to get the distance?? Rospy's time will only give the current time right? I am new to ROS, so please help me! And how do i use "/turtle1/pose" to get the distance and stop the turtle.

Comment: @Anonymous - Numerically integrate your speed.

Comment: take initial time as t0 and present time as t1, speed = v, then your distance is v*(t1-t0)

Comment: Got this!  And what about the maximum value being the circumference?

Comment: the maximum value of your distance should be circumference for your turtle to stop after 1 circle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rosmsg show turtlesim/Pose
```

Get the pose. How are you wanting to know if it did a complete revolution? You could check that the path length is equal to the circumference, or that the rotation angle is back to the start angle, or the horizontal x/y position is the same as the starting position.

Comment: Like i want to stop the turtle after one revolution. How do i stop the turtle at its position which is moving in a circle?

Comment: @Anonymous - I don't understand the question. Your original question was how to track the distance, but now you seem to be asking how to stop the turtle.

Comment: I have to stop the turtle by tracking the distance.